# NodeJS and JBoss through SSL

Tags: java, node.js, ssl, jboss

I have a nodeJS web socket listening on a specific port through SSL.

After a connection is established to that web socket, a request to a REST WS on another machine is made. The WS is deployed on a JBoss server...

The problem is that no request reaches the WS and consequently no response is retrived to nodeJS:

Error: socket hang up

I sucessfully make HTTPS requests to the WS, from the machine running nodeJS using the browser.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can I get some more info? Does the error appears as soon as you made the request, or does it hangs a bit before showing the error? If it hangs, then it's possible the request wasn't complete and you need to call <code>end()</code> on the ClientRequest object. Although get should close the request for you already...

Comment: Thanks! Yes the request hangs a bit before showing the error. What do you mean? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I've edited my old answer to include example

Answer (score 0):

```
https = require('https');

req = https.get({host: 'www.google.com', port: '80'}, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

// Although https.get should end the request for you already,
// try end it yourself.
req.end();
```

Comment: Despite adding that line I still get the same error, and the behaviour is the same... Any more ideas? Bare in mind the nodeJS web socket is listening through HTTPS also...

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you are making the request?